# serialize only some input fields from a parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML format:

```
<div class="product">
...
</div>
...
(n-th row elements)
<div class="product">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="T-Shirt Greenday" name="name[]">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" value="3" name="quantity[]">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

How can I get ONLY the input fields from the n-th row and serialize them with jquery? (I tried with something like this: `parent().parent().siblings('.control-group').children(':input').serialize()`, but no success)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ and then combining it with http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: are you trying to do this when you click "remove"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably calling this code from the `.remove` event handler - but then you have one `.parent()` call too many, getting `div.product` instead. The only visible siblings of this element are `div.product`s, and they have no `:input` children - so you'll end up with an empty jQuery object, and that one is pretty tough to serialize correctly. )

Of course, you can fix it by removing the undeeded `.parent()` call. It's advantageous, however, to get rid off of this chain of `parent()` completely, replacing it with [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    var serializedRow = $(this).closest('.product').find(':input').serialize();
    console.log(serializedRow);
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YbgHt/).

The key advantage of this switch is ability to adjust the innards of `div.product` (adding another wrapper for control groups, for example) without touching the `closest`-using method. Besides, `.closest(some_class)` shows your true intention far clearer than the swarm of `.parent()`s. )

Comment: Yes, it works! This is what I want! Thanks for the extra tips.